# Copy files - SharePoint data to Azure Blob using Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I have a scenerio where i have multiple Parent folders in sharepoint, these folders contain multiple nested or sub folders and then have a file. How can i copy those files to blob by maintaining the same folder structure what we had in Sharepoint using Logic app.

Folder Structure-
Under Document folder i have 2 folders Result and Test .

Result -> Result1 -> Result2 -> test.xlsx

test -> Folder1 -> Folder2 -> Folder3 -> file1.xlsx,file2.xlsx,file3.xlsx

Flow which i tried-

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the design diagram what you have tried?

Comment: I have not tried it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have files in `Test/demo/demo1` folder in SharePoint.

[image]

I am using the below workflow to copy these files to blob storage by keeping the folder structure intact.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Code**-

```json
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Create_blob_(V2)": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": "@body('Get_file_content_using_path')",
                            "headers": {
                                "ReadFileMetadataFromServer": true
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "referenceName": "azureblob"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "post",
                            "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files",
                            "queries": {
                                "folderPath": "/samples-workitems",
                                "name": "@items('For_each')?['Path']",
                                "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Get_file_content_using_path": [
                                "SUCCEEDED"
                            ]
                        },
                        "runtimeConfiguration": {
                            "contentTransfer": {
                                "transferMode": "Chunked"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    },
                    "Get_file_content_using_path": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "referenceName": "sharepointonline"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "get",
                            "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('**********'))}/GetFileContentByPath",
                            "queries": {
                                "inferContentType": true,
                                "path": "@items('For_each')?['Path']",
                                "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('List_folder')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "List_folder": [
                        "SUCCEEDED"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "List_folder": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "referenceName": "sharepointonline"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('*********'))}/folders/@{encodeURIComponent('%252fTest%252fdemo%252fdemo1')}"
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "%252fTest": "/Test",
                    "%252fTest%252fdemo%252fdemo1": "/Test/demo/demo1"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_HTTP_request_is_received": {
                "kind": "Http",
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "concurrency": {
                        "runs": 1
                    }
                },
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateful"
}
```

**Output**-

[image]

[image]

**Update**-

I have two below folder structure-

```
Test -> Folder1 -> Folder2 -> Folder3 -> All the files
Test -> Result -> Result1 -> Result2 -> All the files
```

*My workflow looks like to below*-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

***Code***-

```json
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Condition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Create_blob_(V2)": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "body": "@body('Get_file_content_using_path')",
                                    "headers": {
                                        "ReadFileMetadataFromServer": true
                                    },
                                    "host": {
                                        "connection": {
                                            "referenceName": "azureblob"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "method": "post",
                                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files",
                                    "queries": {
                                        "folderPath": "/samples-workitems",
                                        "name": "@items('For_each')?['{FullPath}']",
                                        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                                    }
                                },
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "Get_file_content_using_path": [
                                        "SUCCEEDED"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                                    "contentTransfer": {
                                        "transferMode": "Chunked"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "ApiConnection"
                            },
                            "Get_file_content_using_path": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "host": {
                                        "connection": {
                                            "referenceName": "sharepointonline"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "method": "get",
                                    "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('**************'))}/GetFileContentByPath",
                                    "queries": {
                                        "inferContentType": true,
                                        "path": "@items('For_each')?['{FullPath}']",
                                        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "ApiConnection"
                            }
                        },
                        "else": {
                            "actions": {}
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "or": [
                                {
                                    "equals": [
                                        "@items('For_each')?['{Path}']",
                                        "Test/Folder/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "equals": [
                                        "@items('For_each')?['{Path}']",
                                        "Test/Result/Result1/Result2/"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "If"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Get_files_(properties_only)')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_files_(properties_only)": [
                        "SUCCEEDED"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "foreach"
            },
            "Get_files_(properties_only)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "referenceName": "sharepointonline"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('*********'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('ea140ea6'))}/getfileitems",
                    "queries": {
                        "viewScopeOption": "RecursiveAll"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_HTTP_request_is_received": {
                "kind": "Http",
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "concurrency": {
                        "runs": 1
                    }
                },
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateful"
}
```

**Output**:-

[image]

[image]

Comment: The above solution works if i use a single folder path. But i have multiple parent folders. I tried from my end. let me provide few details and my workflow which i tried.

Comment: This worked for me. But instead of hardcoding the folder path in Condition statement, i have used "isfolder is not equal true'. this will take folder path for any no. of folder that are available i sharepoint.